# Asp.net Using Load More instead of Datapage in ListView Control

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, listview

I need to understand how can I use Load More Option to the Listview. Initially I am loading 30 rows from Database. Here Instead of datapager I want Load More Button on which click I wan to add 30 more rows everytime when user clicks. Can you help me with what logic need to be apply here? My Listview structure like below

```
<asp:ListView ID="products" runat="server">
    <TtemTemplate>
        <div>
           My Content
        </div>
    <ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
<asp:Button ID="btnLoadMore" runat="server" Text="Load More"></asp:Button>
```

Comment: Double click the button and within the handler write the code to load `30 x numOfPage` rows from the db. `numOfPage` can be stored in a hidden field so you can access it between round trips.

Comment: @CodingYoshi can you show me sample code?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick example of how you can achieve this. The easiest way is to use Linq to get the correct items from a List of objects. For this snippet it is just a List of integers. I uses ViewState to store the page number, but this can also be Session, Cookie etc.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (IsPostBack == false)
    {
        //bind the initial items to the listview
        products.DataSource = getData(0);
        products.DataBind();

        //store the current page number in a viewstate
        ViewState["currentPage"] = 0;
    }
}


public List<int> getData(int pageIndex)
{
    //the numver of items on a page
    int itemsPerPage = 30;

    //create a new list
    List<int> list = new List<int>();

    //add some dummy data
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        list.Add(i);
    }

    //return the list with the correct number of items and offset
    return list.Skip(pageIndex * itemsPerPage).Take(itemsPerPage).ToList();
}


protected void btnLoadMore_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int currentPage = 0;

    //always check if the viewstate exists
    if (ViewState["currentPage"] != null)
    {
        //convert the viewstate back to an int and increment
        currentPage = Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["currentPage"]) + 1;
    }

    //bind the new items to the listview
    products.DataSource = getData(currentPage);
    products.DataBind();

    //update the page number in a viewstate
    ViewState["currentPage"] = currentPage;
}
```

The aspx to make the snippet complete.

```
<asp:ListView ID="products" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <%# Container.DataItem %><br />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
<asp:Button ID="btnLoadMore" OnClick="btnLoadMore_Click" runat="server" Text="Load More"></asp:Button>
```